# Moving secret between azure key vaults from different subscription using DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have 2 different subscriptions (**Dev** & **Prod**) and each subscription we are using separate key vault. So, for Dev- keyvault: **az-kv-dev** & for Prod- keyvault: **az-kv-prod**.

Now, we want to read the secrets from Dev and needs to write all to Prod key vault using Azure DevOps release pipeline. Please note, we do not hard-code the password inside devops.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DevOps. But It seems you could move the key vault(az-kv-dev) to Prod subscription first, then copy all secrets to az-kv-prod.

**Moving Key Vault to a new subscription:**

If the two subscriptions are in the same tenant, you could move just in the portal. Navigate to your key vault -> Overview -> "Move" button. If you move key vault to a subscription in a new tenant, you could use Powershell.

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId <your-subscriptionId>
$vaultResourceId = (Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName myvault).ResourceId
$vault = Get-AzResource –ResourceId $vaultResourceId -ExpandProperties
$vault.Properties.TenantId = (Get-AzContext).Tenant.TenantId
$vault.Properties.AccessPolicies = @()

Set-AzResource -ResourceId $vaultResourceId -Properties $vault.Properties

Clear-AzContext
Connect-AzAccount
```

**Copy all secrets from new-az-kv-dev to az-kv-prod:**

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$sourceVaultName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$destVaultName
)

$secretNames = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName).Name
$secretNames.foreach{
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $destVaultName -Name $_ `
        -SecretValue (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $sourceVaultName -Name $_).SecretValue
}
```

For more details about moving to another subscription, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/move-subscription#moving-key-vault-to-a-new-subscription-within-the-same-tenant).